# appending before element without gap or repetitions jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this problem:

I need to insert an "s" when exists in the div, a singular word "comment" if not.

`<b></b>` has to remain untouchable because this is an image (background).

```js
$(document).on("click","button",function(){

$(document).find(".comments_box:not(:contains('comments')) b").before("s");



})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='comments_box'>comment <b></b> </div>
<hr/>
    <div class='comments_box'>comments <b></b> </div>
<hr/>
    <button>Append an "S"</button>
```

I append the "s" leaving a white gap between the word and the "s", as well, if clicking several times...it continues appending more "s" to the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following solution will work for you. Just trim the text before appending 'S' to it.

```js
   $(document).on("click","button",function(){            
        var $div = $(document).find(".comments_box:not(:contains('comments'))");
        $div.text($div.text().trim()+"s");
 });
```

```html
     


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class='comments_box'>comment <b></b> </div>
        <hr/>
            <div class='comments_box'>comments <b></b> </div>
        <hr/>
            <button>Append an "S"</button>
```

Comment: I was thinking something like that, but I didnt know how to do it.. Yours is definitely the answer. thank you!! +1

Answer (score 1):

Remove blank space between "comment" text and "b" tag.

```js
$(document).on("click","button",function(){

 $(document).find(".comments_box:not(:contains('comments')) b").before("s");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='comments_box'>comment<b></b> </div>
<hr/>
    <div class='comments_box'>comments <b></b> </div>
<hr/>
    <button>Append an "S"</button>
```